# If $(E_k,\mathcal E_k,\lambda_k)$ is a measure space, is there a name for the measure $B\mapsto\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}\lambda_k(B\cap E_k)$

Tags: measure-theory

Really short question: Say $(E_k,\mathcal E_k,\lambda_k)$ is a measure space for all $k\in\mathbb N$. We may equip $E:=\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb N}E_k$ with the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal E:=\sigma(E)$ and define the measure $$\lambda(B):=\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}\lambda_k(B\cap E_k)\;\;\;\text{for }B\in\mathcal E$$ on the latter.

Is there a name for this construction?

Comment: So you have a space $X$ and subsets $E_k \subseteq X,$ which (might) have different $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{E}_k$ and measures $\lambda_k$? There's no requirement that the $E_k$:s are disjoint? Or do they form a partition of the full space (which I call $X$ and which will equal $E = \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} E_k$?

Comment: @md2perpe Well, for the particular instance that I've got in mind, the $E_k$ are disjoint. But I don't think that this is a necessity.

Answer (score 0):

I would just call it *sum of $\lambda_k$ extended to the full space $E$*:

Let $\bar{\lambda}_k$ be defined on $\mathcal{E}$ by
$\bar{\lambda}_k(B) := \lambda_k(B \cap E_k).$
Then $\lambda(B) = \sum_k \bar{\lambda}_k(B)$ i.e. $\lambda = \sum_k \bar{\lambda}_k$.